# Fetch SUM from MySQl database using PHP and then print it in android textview

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need some help. I want to calculate the SUM of an amount column and then display it in a text view on my android app.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class BalanceActivity extends SwipeFunctionActivity
{
private Boolean exit = false;
Button buttonExpense, buttonIncome, buttonSaving;
ImageView helpImageView;
TextView totalIncomeNumberTV;
String ftotalintv = "http://192.168.0.3/myapp/ftotalintv.php";
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance);

    buttonExpense = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonExpense);
    buttonIncome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonIncome);
    buttonSaving = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSaving);

    helpImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.helpImageView);

    totalIncomeNumberTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalIncomeNumberTV);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    try
    {
        fetchTotalIncome();
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    buttonExpense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addExpenseMethod();
        }
    });

    buttonIncome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addIncomeMethod();
        }
    });

    buttonSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            addSavingMethod();
        }
    });

    helpImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            instructionsMethod();
        }
    });

}

public void fetchTotalIncome() throws JSONException /*throws JSONException*/
{



    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ftotalintv, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("transactions");
                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject test = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String totalIncome = test.getString("TotalIncome");

                    totalIncomeNumberTV.append(totalIncome);
                }
            }

            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
//
//        String data = "http://192.168.0.3/myapp/ftotalintv.php";
//        JSONObject jObject;
//        jObject = new JSONObject(data);
//        String total = jObject.getString("TotalIncome");
//        totalIncomeNumberTV.setText(ftotalintv);


    //totalIncomeNumberTV.setText("troll");
}

public void addExpenseMethod()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddExpenseActivity.class));
}

public void addIncomeMethod()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddIncomeActivity.class));
}

public void addSavingMethod()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddSavingActivity.class));
}

public void instructionsMethod()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InstructionsActivity.class));
    //finish();
}

@Override
public void onSwipeLeft()
{
    super.onSwipeLeft();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TransactionsActivity.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSwipeRight()
{
    super.onSwipeRight();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpenseCategoriesActivity.class));
    finish();
}

public void onSwipeTop()
{
    super.onSwipeRight();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChartActivity.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (exit)
    {
        finish(); // finish activity
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                exit = false;
            }
        }
                , 3 * 1000);

    }
}
```

}

And here is my PHP file with the SUM query:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, SUM(TransAmount) AS 'TotalIncome' FROM transactions WHERE TransType = 'income';");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$sum = $row['TotalIncome'];

if($query)
{
    echo $sum;
}

myslqi_close($con);
?>
```

As you can see i have some things commented inside my code. I tried to display the SUM with the Volley library but i failed. Please can someone help me? I really dont know what to do at this point. I need mostly help in the android app because the PHP file when i run it in the browser it works, but there is the possibility of having some problems there as well.

Comment: Typo: `myslqi_close($con);` should be `mysqli_close($con);`

Comment: Yea thanks for that. I fixed the typo but still when i run the app the totalIncomeNumberTV does not change to the SUM from my database, which means that was not the problem. I want this text view http://prntscr.com/b0ea58 to change to 400 http://prntscr.com/b0ead7 because 400 is the SUM of income in my database

Comment: I need a way/method to print this SUM in a text view. That is my problem i don't know how to do it...i 've been searching for the last 3 days. I am stuck :/

Comment: This is are two different questions in one.

Comment: I know good sir, but this is the most important problem i have now. As i said the PHP file works so it was not my question. Thankfully i got some tips to improve it but i made this thread in order to ask how to update the text view in my android app using this php file. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php script you didnt encode  your response in json and you may be didn't add json header as well in your php code. So your php code will be something like this

```
$sum = $row['TotalIncome'];
if($query)
{
   $data[]['TotalIncome'] = $sum;
   $result = array("transactions" => $data);
   echo json_encode($result);
}
myslqi_close($con);
```

Dont forget to add json type header in most top of the php script

Comment: Thank you so much Sir...this solved my problem and my label updates now properly. Thanks again so much !!!!